# Action Script 3.0 : How to extract two value from string.?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flashvars

HI

I have a URL

```
var str:String = "conn=rtmp://server.com/service/&fileId=myfile.flv"
```

or

```
var str:String = "fileId=myfile.flv&conn=rtmp://server.com/service/"
```

The **str** might be like this, But i need to get the value of "conn" and "fileId" from the string.

how can i write a function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're having trouble with the second '=' in the string. Fortunatly, ActionScript's `String.Split` method supports splitting on strings, so the following code should work:

```
var str:String = "conn=rtmp://server.com/service/&fileId=myfile.flv";
var conn:String = (str + "&").Split("conn=")[1].Split("&")[0];
```

and

```
var str:String = "fileId=myfile.flv&conn=rtmp://server.com/service/";
var fileId:String = (str + "&").Split("fileId=")[1].Split("&")[0];
```

Note: I'm appending a `&` to the string, in case the string didn't contain any url parameters beyond the one we're looking for.

Comment: Yes, you did. But it contains a for-loop, doesn't handle single-parameter URLs and has no explanation. Not very nice of you to downgrade a more complete answer. :-\

Comment: My answer can handle any number of arguments, it won't lag because it have a simple for loop -__-

Answer (score 1):

```
var str:String = "fileId=myfile.flv&conn=rtmp://server.com/service/"
var fa:Array = str.split("&");
for(var i:uint=0;i<fa.length;i++)
    fa[i] = fa[i].split('=');
```

That's how the "fa" variable be in the end:

fa = 
[
["fileId","myfile.flv"],
["conn","rtmp://server.com/service/"]
]

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url:String = "fileId=myfile.flv&conn=rtmp://server.com/service/";

 var strArray:Array = url.split(/=/);

trace(strArray[0]) //Just to test
```

returns an array, with the word 'conn or fileid' in index 0 - 2 (anything even), alternatives of 1, 3 is the information within.

---

Or was it something else you needed?

Comment: Did you test the code? strArray=["fileId","yfile.flv&conn","rtmp://server.com/service/"]